# adding custom action won't start the activity when running it in the emulator

Tags: android, action, manifest, intentfilter

I have the following code in my Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.fletech.android.apparent.CategoriesGrid"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When I run the app in Eclipse it starts this activity in the emulator, as expected.

But when I also add:

```
<action android:name="com.fletech.android.apparent.action.APPARENT_MAIN" />
```

right below the other action, and run the app, it only installs it to the emulator but doesn't run it. Why?

What I wanted to achieve is this: I would like to be able to show a dialog to the user (from another apps) to chose between all my apps that have "com.fletech.android.apparent.action.APPARENT_MAIN" as an action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to specify another launch scenario, you should just add another whole intent-filter block rather than putting all of the action clauses in the same one.